# is there a way to get two <h> tags to sit flush with one another (no auto line break)?

Tags: html, css

I have two h3 tags one after the other with the same background colour. I want them to sit flush so the colour spreads across both tags. When i add either top or bottom padding, it just shifts the h3 tag up/down. Is there a way to stop this auto line break with heading tags?

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: You want them to sit in the same line?

Comment: If one of those headlines is for a subtitle or tagline, it is considered to be an incorrect usage of the hn elements (see: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple css.

```
h3 {float:left;}
```

Or

```
h3 {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason they automatically break onto a new line is because header tags have `display: block`. I would recommend giving the headers the following style:

```
h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Inline-block means that they will be able to sit next to each other like `inline` elements, but you will also be able to alter the height and width of them like a regular `block` element.